# Out of Memory error at model.compile

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a relatively large multi-layer regression model that I want to train end-to-end. My training is a two-step procedure in which I first minimize the euclidean loss and then I minimize my loss. Effectively, this means the following pseudo-code:

```
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse')
model.fit()
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=my_metric)
model.fit()
```

I am able to run the first two statements without any problems. But I get an out of memory error when my code reaches the second model.compile statement. What should I do differently to avoid this problem ?

Edited to include my_metric. Think of y_true and y_pred as 3-dim vectors. First I'm minimizing the euclidean distance between them to initialize the weights and then I minimize a geodesic loss between them.

```
# compute geodesic viewpoint loss
def my_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    # compute angles
    angle_true = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true), axis=1))
    angle_pred = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred), axis=1))
    # compute axes
    axis_true = K.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=1)
    axis_pred = K.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=1)
    # convert axes to corresponding skew-symmetric matrices
    proj = tf.constant(np.asarray([[0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0]]), dtype=tf.float32)
    skew_true = K.dot(axis_true, proj)
    skew_pred = K.dot(axis_pred, proj)
    skew_true = K.map_fn(lambda x: K.reshape(x, [3, 3]), skew_true)
    skew_pred = K.map_fn(lambda x: K.reshape(x, [3, 3]), skew_pred)
    # compute rotation matrices and do a dot product
    R = tf.map_fn(my_R, (skew_true, skew_pred, angle_true, angle_pred), dtype=tf.float32)
    # compute the angle error
    theta = K.map_fn(get_theta, R)
    return K.mean(theta)

# function to compute R1^T R2 given the axis angle representations (\theta_1, v_1) and (\theta_2, v_2)
# x is a list that contains x[0] = v_1, x[1] = v_2, x[2] = \theta_1, x[3] = \theta_2
# note that the v_1 and v_2 are skew-symmetric matrices corresponding to the 3-dim vectors in this function
def my_R(x):
    R1 = K.eye(3) + K.sin(x[2]) * x[0] + (1.0 - K.cos(x[2])) * K.dot(x[0], x[0])
    R2 = K.eye(3) + K.sin(x[3]) * x[1] + (1.0 - K.cos(x[3])) * K.dot(x[1], x[1])
    return K.dot(K.transpose(R1), R2)


# Rodrigues' formula
def get_theta(x):
    return K.abs(tf.acos(K.clip(0.5*(tf.reduce_sum(tf.diag_part(x))-1.0), -1.0+1e-7, 1.0-1e-7)))
```

Comment: Can you post the code to your metric?

Comment: I don't know the code you're using, but you quoted the first loss and didn't quote the second loss...

Comment: Edited to include my_metric. Thank you for your responses and apologies for the delay in replying back.

Comment: If you just call compile on your metric do things go out-of-memory?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was able to resolve the issue...